# Why does not deletion reduce indexed file size in lucene?

Tags: indexing, document

```
    IndexWriter writer = null;
    try {
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(path));
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(LUCENE_VERSION);
        IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(LUCENE_VERSION, analyzer);
        iwc.setRAMBufferSizeMB(getIndexRamBufferSizeMB());
        iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
        writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);

        Term term = new Term(request.getIndexKeyName(), String.valueOf(request.getId()));
        writer.deleteDocuments(term);
        writer.deleteUnusedFiles();         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.commit();
                writer.close(true);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I can delete the document but index file size not reduce, especially _a.fdt, _a_Lucene41_0.pos.

Before deleting _a.fdt size 10037kb, after deleting all document, size is the same.

Help please?

Comment: Solved!. I use **writer.forceMergeDeletes()** after **writer.deleteUnusedFiles()** then it delete all files except segments_c and segment_gen. Is useing of these methods true?

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is optimised for search speed.

Re-organising a file to reclaim space freed by a delete requires disk I/O, which is a pretty expensive operation (in comparison to both RAM and reading the file from disk).  So when you delete a file from the index, this doesn't tell Lucene to do this (expensive) reorganisation.

To free the space, you can use `expungeDeletes()` which basically frees the disk space, or `optimize()` which would take a bit more effort, may improve search performance.

Comment: I was not able to use these methods. Because lucene version doesnot suuport these methods. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> Solved!. I use `writer.forceMergeDeletes()` after `writer.deleteUnusedFiles()` then it delete all files except `segments_c` and `segment_gen`.

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)